# how to put an angular button component into a bootstrap button group

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have the following button group:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <app-remove-button></app-remove-button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">b2
  </button>
</div>
```

app-remove-button is a component with the template:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button" ngbTooltip="hint">
<b>&times;</b></button>
```

this is not rendered correctly:

[image]

the html output is:

[image]

how can I make it look like:

[image]

Comment: do you have a fiddle to show the code running

Comment: probably want to remove the right border radius

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Change the selector of your component :

> app-remove-button → [app-remove-button]

You can now use it an an attribute (getting rid of the selector added in the final HTML that messes up your style) :

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button app-remove-button></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">b2
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this. It turned out to be very complex. Setting the classes is not easy and I have no idea how to add the tooltip. Is there an easy way to set classes and other properties/attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Extend your bootstrap CSS with following code:

```
.btn-group > [in-group]:not(:first-child) > .btn {
  margin-left: -1px; 
}

.btn-group > [in-group]:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) > .btn {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0; 
}

.btn-group > [in-group]:not(:first-child) > .btn {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0; 
}
```

And then in your component buttons add `in-group` attribute.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <app-remove-button in-group></app-remove-button>
</div>
```